# Calculus of Variations

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

When considering all possible paths $\left[t_1,\,t_2\right]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for an extremum of the action, do we consider only continuous paths, or all paths in general?

In other words, when seeking solutions to the second order differential equation that is Newton's 2nd law, do we look only for continuous solutions, or for all general solutions?

If we look only for continuous solutions, what is the (physical) reason for that?

If we don't look only for continuous solutions, what is the Banach space (of trajectories) on which the action acts? Viewing the action as a map $$S:\mathcal{B}\to\mathbb{R}$$where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Banach space of all trajectories $\left[t_1,\,t_2\right]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and naively I would put $$\mathcal{B}=C\left(\left[t_1,\,t_2\right]\to\mathbb{R}^n\right)$$ (the space of all such continuous maps) together with the sup-norm. The sup-norm is well-defined because the continuous image of a compact space is again compact, hence bounded by Heine-Borel in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Any formal explanation to this would be greatly appreciated. Especially an emphasis on the physics behind choosing to vary only on continuous paths (if that is indeed true).

Comment: In physics, any real trajectory can be approximated by a smooth function to an arbitrary precision, and thus in practice we don't really *need* non-smooth functions (this doesn't mean that we cannot ask how general the space of trajectories can be, just for the fun of it).

Comment: This question (v1) seems too broad. It depends on the physics system at hand.

Comment: But you'd still have to show that the extremum over all continuous functions is the same as the extremum over all functions in general.

Comment: @Qmechanic if need be you may specify to the example of an ideal ball attached to a spring in classical mechanics.

Comment: We only look at continuous(in fact, twice differentiable) curves in the Euler-Lagrange prescription, as AccidentalFourierTransform mentioned, classical trajectories are smooth. If we weren't looking at differentiable curves, then the derivation of the E-L equations wouldn't make any sense as varying the lagrangian by the chain rule would be nonsense.

Comment: @BobakHashemi  but this is an aposteri explanation since it uses the result of the variation (the euler lagrange equations) as the justification. Is there a possibility that you don't assume differentiability a priori and then get a different extremum?

Comment: I agree with Bobak Hashemi, but maybe you have more general considerations in mind that I am not able to see. If the Lagrangian depends on the first derivative, then the action is ill-defined in $\mathbb{R}^{[t_1,t_2]}$. And then indeed, the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equations is even more restrictive as in requires the derivative to be at least piecewise continuous (maybe even more) afaik.

Comment: @PPR if you allow for non-differentiable paths, then yes: there are in general extrema that are not differentiable, and these are missed by the EL equations. Classical paths are always regular. Some non-smooth paths have an action that is lower than that of the smooth solution, so we naïvely should choose those. But Hamilton's principle restrict the family of solutions to those that are smooth, and this agrees with experiments: we never observe non-smooth paths (even if there exists some non-smooth path with lower action than the minimising smooth path).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, how do you define "regular"? How do you know classical paths are always regular? What is the physical reason to restrict to smooth paths if the extremal action of non-smooth paths is different than that of smooth paths?

Comment: Oh, and if you only require Lebesgue integrability of $\mathcal{L}(f)$, it seems that you lose the uniqueness of the solution as paths that are equal up to a null set would have the same action.

Comment: @PPR regular=$C^\infty$=smooth. We know that classical paths are always smooth because of observations: Hamilton principle perfectly agrees with experiments (within the realm of classical physics, of course). (Some people would say that in QM one allows for nowhere differentiable paths, though I'm not sure this interpretation of the path integral is useful at all)

Comment: Wait, does your question have anything to do with the least action principle ? After re-reading it and going through the comments it now seems to me that you are just asking very generally why theories of mechanics only involve continuous paths/fields ?

Comment: @LucasGautheron, Yes it is about the least action principle. It is about why the "least" should be taken over continuous paths.

Comment: @PPR then for me, as stated in my previous comments, the least action formulation would not make sense otherwise (for proper definiteness and uniqueness arguments)

Comment: Isn't the actual physical restriction that if $\gamma$ a particle's trajectory, then $\gamma$ should at least be continuous, i.e $C^0$, meaning that the particle does not ``jump" (intuitively speaking)? But then $C^0$ does not imply $C^k$ (and therefore $C^\infty$) in general.